# New users are not able to create an account and Login and Register urls are redirection to same page Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to build a simple authentication system using Django. Both Login and Register urls on 'accounts' are redirecting to the same Login page. After I login as an admin, I'm redirected to register page. In the register page, I'm not able to register new accounts. Please tell me what I'm missing.

urls.py-login

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

urls.py-accounts

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.indexView, name = "home"),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboardView, name = "dashboard"),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name = "login_url"),
    path('register/',views.registerView, name = "register_url"),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='dashboard'), name = "logout"),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def indexView(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def dashboardView(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')

@login_required
def registerView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login_url')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':form})
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Petrol Pump Management System</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
        <h1>User Authentication</h1>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>

            {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'login_url' %}">Login</a>
            <a href="{% url 'register_url' %}">Register</a>
            {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Welcome to Petrol Pump Management Service, {{user.username}}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

register.html

```
{% extends 'index.html'%}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Create new account</h1>
    <form method = "POST" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>System Login</h1>
    <form method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your register view is redirecting to the login URl because you're using the `login_required` decorator. As for your other questions: do you have the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting set, and if so what is the value? And how do you know the registration of new accounts is not working, are there errors being thrown? It looks like the register view should work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DJRamones In settings.py, I have set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/dashboard/'. When I login as an admin on Django administration, I don't see the newly registered accounts in the users list. All the registered user account should show up there, right?

Comment: @DJRamones Any suggestions regarding why my register url is also being redirected to Login page?

Comment: Just remove the `@login_required` line; you intend to allow anonymous users to sign-up, right? Then you shouldn't be asking for them to be logged-in when they are just about to sign-up for an account. As for your other concerns, about being redirected to the registration page when logging in as admin, or being unable to register accounts—I ran your code and I didn't encounter those issues. Admin could log-in just fine, and users were being created upon registration.

Comment: Just a thought—are you using Django's default User model, or are you using something custom?

Comment: @DJRamones  I removed `@login_required` and the register url is being redirected to register page. Thank you. But I'm still not able to register new users. Sometimes I get the Forbidden(403) error, sometimes I don't. When I don't get the error, I type in the username and password and hit register, the cursor will return back to username field. I have no issues logging in as an admin but I see that new users aren't showing up on admin page. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DJRamones I'm using Django's default User model.

Comment: Based on just your code, I still have no idea what the issue is. The unpredictable 403 errors are strange; your registration view has no permissions checks at all, so it's a mystery why Django is returning a 403. As I've said, I have run your code on my own machine and it's working as it should, so maybe there's something about your configuration. Are you developing on localhost, using `runserver`? For the creation of users, instead of relying on the admin page, have you tried querying your database directly to see if there are new records in the users table?

Comment: @DJRamones Yes, I'm developing on localhost, using `runserver`. I don't have a database as such to query because I am just trying to understand the basics of Django.

Comment: Don't understand why it isn't working on my system :/

Comment: But Django won't run without a database. If you're using mostly default configurations (sounds like you do), then you're probably using SQLite. There would be a `db.sqlite3` file in your project's root directory. There are a lot of tools you can use to inspect that database, such as [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). If you want to understand Django's basics, you must at least have an idea of how it uses databases.

Comment: Sorry if I worded it wrong, didn't mean Django works without a database. I meant that I'm not using any external database.

Comment: Hello, I got it working. I just restarted the system and it worked. Don't know how that makes sense! Thank you :)